# Angular template: Disable div in production mode

Tags: angular, typescript, production-environment

I have several `div`s in my webapp that are used solely for debugging, and I would like to remove these in production mode.

In my templates, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<div *ngIf=!environment.production>{{ fooState | async | json}}</div>
```

However, this fails when running `ng serve --prod` with the following error:

> ERROR in src/app/foo/foo.component.html(18,6): : Property 'environment' does not exist on type 'Foo'

Is there any way to disable these in production mode without adding another field to each component?

I'm using Angular cli 1.7.4 and Angular 5.2.10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could create a directive to only show your div elements if environment.production is false. Something like in this blitzstack example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eziobx

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environment';

/**
 * usage: <div *hideProd></div>
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[hideProd]'
})
export class HideProdDirective implements OnInit{

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(!environment.prod){
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your condition is right: `*ngIf="!environment.production"`

Though you need to import the environment object in your component.

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  public environment = environment;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works but it's not quite what I was looking for.